# Raspberry Pi : use VLC to stream webcam : Logitech C920 [H264 Video without transcoding + Audio + LED control] - SpyCam / BabyCam

Tags: http, raspberry-pi3, webcam, raspbian, vlc

I have a RaspberryPi and a Logitech C920 Webcam.
I want to use these devices to work as a surveillance / babycam, i.e. : **Stream audio + video over HTTP (or any other protocol) without cpu intensive video 
 transcoding**

The C920 webcam is able to stream H264 natively, so theoretically I won't need to ask RaspberyPi+VLC to transcode the video stream.

The built-in C920 Microphone stream does not seem to be included in the webcam stream.
Cam and microphone are 2 separate devices.

The C920 also has a built-in led indicator. I want to control that to avoid the LED to ligth up while recording.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This solution is tested and working with versions indicated below.
Using this method, the RaspberryPi3 is always around 5% CPU.

edit 2018-11-18:
One can also see the all-in-one solution prototype on [RaspiVWS project homepage](https://lonewanderer-gh.github.io/RaspiVWS/) (for curious people, see [GitHub project](https://github.com/LoneWanderer-GH/RaspiVWS))

**0. Preliminary checks**

**1. Webcam video configuration**

**2. Microphone identification**

**3. Stream using VLC**

**4. Make RaspberryPi3+ a Wifi access point**
(If you have no existing network to connect your Pi to)

**5. Script at startup or as a service**

**6. [EDIT] Additional commands : infinite loop recording & split video**

**7. [EDIT] Program execution at a given instant**

**8. [EDIT] TROUBLESHOOTING**

---

## 0. Preliminary checks

The answer is working with Raspbian 9.4 Stretch.
Check your version with the following command :

```
lsb_release -a
```

You should see:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch)
Release:        9.4
Codename:       stretch
```

We can rely on the following tools :

- v4l allows to control the webcam. It offers the command `v4l2-ctl` which will allows us to control and config the webcam.
- VLC which is not only a video player, but also has powerful streaming capabilities

You can install them with the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
sudo apt-get install v4l-utils
```

Once everything is installed, you can configure your C920 webcam.

---

## 1. Webcam video configuration

`v4l2-ctl --all` lists all available devices and their config

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ v4l2-ctl --all
Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
    Driver name   : uvcvideo
    Card type     : HD Pro Webcam C920
    Bus info      : usb-3f980000.usb-1.5
    Driver version: 4.14.30
    Capabilities  : 0x84200001
        Video Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps   : 0x04200001
        Video Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
Format Video Capture:
    Width/Height      : 1920/1080
    Pixel Format      : 'H264'
    Field             : None
    Bytes per Line    : 3840
    Size Image        : 4147200
    Colorspace        : sRGB
    Transfer Function : Default
    YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default
    Quantization      : Default
    Flags             : 
Crop Capability Video Capture:
    Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 1920, Height 1080
    Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 1920, Height 1080
    Pixel Aspect: 1/1
Selection: crop_default, Left 0, Top 0, Width 1920, Height 1080
Selection: crop_bounds, Left 0, Top 0, Width 1920, Height 1080
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
    Capabilities     : timeperframe
    Frames per second: 30.000 (30/1)
    Read buffers     : 0
                     brightness (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=-8193 value=128
                       contrast (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=57343 value=128
                     saturation (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=57343 value=128
 white_balance_temperature_auto (bool)   : default=1 value=1
                           gain (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=57343 value=255
           power_line_frequency (menu)   : min=0 max=2 default=2 value=2
      white_balance_temperature (int)    : min=2000 max=6500 step=1 default=57343 value=4822 flags=inactive
                      sharpness (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=57343 value=128
         backlight_compensation (int)    : min=0 max=1 step=1 default=57343 value=0
                  exposure_auto (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=0 value=3
              exposure_absolute (int)    : min=3 max=2047 step=1 default=250 value=333 flags=inactive
         exposure_auto_priority (bool)   : default=0 value=1
                   pan_absolute (int)    : min=-36000 max=36000 step=3600 default=0 value=0
                  tilt_absolute (int)    : min=-36000 max=36000 step=3600 default=0 value=0
                 focus_absolute (int)    : min=0 max=250 step=5 default=8189 value=0 flags=inactive
                     focus_auto (bool)   : default=1 value=1
                  zoom_absolute (int)    : min=100 max=500 step=1 default=57343 value=100
                      led1_mode (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=3
                 led1_frequency (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=0 value=0
```

The last 2 lines gives us clues to control the built-in LED indicator, for instance, to deactivate the LED indicator.
The `-d0` parameter indicates on which device the modifcation should be applied (if you ahve several cams or its device name changed)

```
v4l2-ctl -d0 --set-ctrl=led1_mode=0
v4l2-ctl -d0 --set-ctrl=led1_frequency=30
```

## 2. Microphone identification

The command `arecord -l` will give us the list of ALSA devices. (ALSA is the audio manager in RaspberryPi)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arecord -l
**** Liste des Périphériques Matériels CAPTURE ****
carte 1: C920 [HD Pro Webcam C920], périphérique 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
```

This means that the built-in microphone is located on `hardware 1, periph 0`. You can check that in command line with `alsamixer -c 1 -V capture`

## 3. Stream using VLC

VLC can be launched using command line.
Since we do not have video and audio already mixed together in a single stream access, we need to ask VLC to do that.
It is the role of the `transcoding` feature of VLC.

1. Stream over HTTP

We also want to stream over HTTP, VLC can also achieve that.

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264 :input-slave=alsa://hw:1,0 --sout '#transcode{acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,threads=4,audio-sync=1}:standard{access=http,mux=ts,mime=video/ts,dst=:8099}'
```

Explanation

- `v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264` gives VLC input data : it grabs the video stream from /dev/video0 and that it is a h264 encoding (if your webcam is the 0th video device, it could also be another number, refer to `v4l2-ctl --all` command)
- `:input-slave=alsa://hw:1,0` tells VLC to take another input stream with the video. It is the audio stream identified from the `arecord` above
- `--sout` tells VLC how to handle the output stream
- `#transcode{acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,threads=4,audio-sync=1}` tells VLC to convert the audio to `mpga` codec, 128 kbits/s, 2 channels, 44100 Hz sampling, using all 4 RaspberryPi3+ cores. audiosync is optional. It took me some time to realize this : the webcam h264 video stream is kept as provided (no video transcoding).
- `:standard{access=http,mux=ts,mime=video/ts,dst=:8099}` tells VLC to provide stream over HTTP on port 8099 with the TS muxing format.

On any other device, you can use VLC to access your RaspberryPi3+ VLC stream :
`vlc http://<raspberrypi-ip>:8099`

It works with any VLC client :

- windows
- unix
- mac
- confirmed with iPhone 7 (v11.2.1 (15C153)) with VLC app (3.0.3 (305))

NB : Having the video already in H264 1920x1080 30fps in output of the webcam saves a lot of RaspberryPi3+ CPU.

2. Different containers

You can also record to various containers, or even containers + stream, here are some examples:

- record to MKV
  `cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264 :input-slave=alsa://hw:1,0 --sout '#transcode{acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,threads=4,audio-sync=1}:standard{access=file,mux=mkv,dst='/home/pi/Webcam_Record/MyVid.mkv'}'`
- record to MP4
  `cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264 :input-slave=alsa://hw:1,0 --sout '#transcode{acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,threads=4,audio-sync=1}:standard{access=file,mux=mp4,dst='/home/pi/Webcam_Record/MyVid.mp4'}'`
- record + stream
  `cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264 :input-slave=alsa://hw:1,0 --sout '#transcode{acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,threads=4,audio-sync=1}:duplicate{dst=standard{access=file,mux=mp4,dst='/home/pi/Webcam_Record/MyVid.mp4'},dst=standard{access=http,mux=ts,mime=video/ts,dst=:8099}}'`

  3. Format filenames, timestamps

You can also use formatted string for filenames. Prefix command like this:

```
cvlc --sout-file-format v4l2:///dev/video0:<...> dst='/home/pi/Webcam_Record/%F_%T_MyVid.mp4'}
```

It will produce a file named `YYYY-MM-DD_HH:MM:SS_MyVid.mp4` (`:` are authorized in unix filenames, but not in windows filenames)

## 4. Make RaspberryPi3+ a Wifi access point

If you have no existing network to connect your Pi to:
You can follow instructions from official RaspberryPi3+ website : https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

Otherwise, if you already have a network you can connect to your pi using its IP.
See part 3

> On any other device, you can use VLC to access your RaspberryPi3+ VLC
>   stream : `vlc http://<raspberrypi-ip>:8099`

## 5. Script at startup

You can put many commands into a bash file `my_bash_file.sh`.
For instance :

```
#!/bin/bash
# auto stream launch + led off
#cvlc -vvv for verbose debug

# change this value to adapt to your webcam device number
deviceNb=0

# force video format + led off
v4l2-ctl -d${deviceNb} --set-fmt-video=width=1920,height=1080,pixelformat=1 --set-ctrl=led1_mode=0

# if delay needed 
# cvlc v4l2:///dev/video${deviceNb}:chroma=h264 :input-slave=alsa://hw:1,0  :live-caching=2500  --sout '#transcode{acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,threads=4,audio-sync=1}:standard{access=http,mux=ts,mime=video/ts,dst=:8099}'

# no delay
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video${deviceNb}:chroma=h264 :input-slave=alsa://hw:1,0 --sout '#transcode{acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,threads=4,audio-sync=1}:standard{access=http,mux=ts,mime=video/ts,dst=:8099}'
```

1. Basic method

You can then make the `rc.local` script use your custom script to be executed at startup.
You can follow instructions from official RaspberryPi3+ website : https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md

2. Another method : Create a deamon service

We will create a "webcam-stream" service, assuming all necessary bash commands are located `/home/pi/Webcam_Record/vlc_webcam_stream_service.sh`

```
cd /lib/systemd/system/
sudo nano webcam-stream.service
```

And write in it:

```
[Unit]
Description=Custom Webcam Streaming Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/pi/Webcam_Record/vlc_webcam_stream_service.sh
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Make the service file and the script executable:

```
sudo chmod 644 /lib/systemd/system/webcam-stream.service
chmod +x /home/pi/Webcam_Record/vlc_webcam_stream.sh
```

Allow VLC to be excuted as root:

```
sudo sed -i 's/geteuid/getppid/' /usr/bin/vlc
```

Reload deamons and enable our service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable webcam-stream.service
```

Check it is recognized and working:

```
sudo service webcam-stream status
sudo service webcam-stream start
```

You can check with another computer that the video is correctly streamed.
Note that the webcam won't be available while the service is running.

---

Once you're done, you can connect to the RaspberryPi3+ wifi access point and access your video stream.

---

## 6. [EDIT] Additional commands : infinite loop recording & split video

The following bash scripts allows infinite recording of 15 s long videos with timestamped filenames and streaming

```
#!/bin/bash
# auto stream launch + led off
#cvlc -vvv for verbose debug

# adapt to video device name
deviceNb=1

# loop duration
duration=15

#infinite recording
#loopOption=
loopOption=--loop

# force video format + led off
v4l2-ctl -d ${deviceNb} --set-fmt-video=width=1920,height=1080,pixelformat=1 --set-ctrl=led1_mode=0

# if delay needed :live-caching=2500
cvlc --sout-file-format --run-time=${duration} ${loopOption} v4l2:///dev/video${deviceNb}:chroma=h264 :input-slave=alsa://hw:1,0 --sout '#transcode{acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,threads=4,audio-sync=1}:duplicate{dst=standard{access=file,mux=mp4,dst='/home/pi/Webcam_Record/%F_%T_Spy.mp4'}:dst=standard{access=http,mux=ts,mime=video/ts,dst=:8099}'
```

---

### 7. [EDIT] Program execution at a given instant

EDIT 04 aug 2018

To launch the execution today at 14:00, you can use the following command:

```
./my_vlc_webcam_script.sh | at 1400
```

See the `at` command manual for further details.

---

### 8. TROUBLESHOOTING

EDIT 07 jul 2018

I recently ran into VLC error after a dist-upgrade:

```
VLC media player 2.2.6 Umbrella (revision 2.2.6-0-g1aae78981c)
[00acb230] pulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
```

The solution I found is to launch VLC in GUI mode and change the default audio device to ALSA (instead of Automatic). I can also be done in command line.
See the solution found here [VLC issues with PulseAudio](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=29403)

```
cvlc -A alsa,none --alsa-audio-device default
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once. The configuration for this stuff is really complicated and this is the first comprehensive explanation I have seen.

Comment: I'm having an issue with sound with the bash file you provided.

Sound is not recorded the first time I execute the script. Video works, no sounds.

If I terminate the stream on the pi, and start it again, the second time the sound works.

The sound also works subsequent times.

I have seen some people having the inverse problem where it works initially and then does not work subsequent times. I think it's the same issue, but that is how it manifests with pulse audio as the default. I set the VLC default to ALSA, and that has the inverse problem somehow.

Comment: Hi, I did not face this kind of problem on my Pi. Is your Pi up to date (distribution and packages) ?

Comment: Or maybe you have another program that takes precedence over the device ?

Comment: Tried to make it work today, but somehting must be broken `led1_mode (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=3` does not appear anymore in the webcam capabilities ...

Comment: I don't mind if the LED stays on. It might actually be preferable in my use case, but it's not a big issue either way.

The sound is a minor problem as well, I am happy enough to have stable video and if I need sound I can just restart it.

However. I would be put at ease a bit if there no problems at all. I am using 9.4 stretch.

I believe that this reproduces with the newest v4l2-ctl and vlc, but I am trying to configure multiple pis for this job and I think I have tried different configurations on different ones.

Comment: Well, after verification today I’m facing the same sound issue (+ led control) since dist-upgrade 2 days ago ... I consider opening a ticket for raspbian.

Comment: Post opened on raspberrypi stackexchange for these two issues :  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85740/raspbian-stretch-c920-webcam-driver-led-control-regression

Comment: I consider making a more configurable script and posting it on github, when I get time for this.

Comment: use ' :live-caching=1000 --sout-keep' to fix the audio issue

Comment: Thanks @JonathanEustace I put a first bash project on github but I've come up with a greater idea that needs some global rethinking. I'll need some time to think of it and a lot more to do it :D

Comment: It looks like at some point either the uvc driver, the c920 firmware, or vlc changed the API a bit. I'm running kernel 5.4 on Slackware-current and I was unable to get this to work using `cvlc ... :chroma=h264 ...` and after much banging of head and searching found that I needed to set ti to `cvlc ... :chroma=mjpg ...` instead. `v4l2-ctl -d 0 --all` also shows the pixel format as MJPG and not H264 on my setup. Perhaps a note should be added to the answer? Thanks for your hard work!

Comment: If `led1_mode` is not showing up, try plugging in differernt USB ports.

Comment: known bug VLC 3.0.16 vlc does not accept the alsa url https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/26054 so `:input-slave=alsa://hw:1,0` won't work with this VLC version

Answer (score 1):

You need the  `vcodec=` for video to work and `deinterlace` if you want that.

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264
                       :input-slave=alsa://hw:1,0
                       :live-caching=2500
--sout '#transcode{
                     deinterlace,
                     vcodec=mpgv,
                     acodec=mpga,
                     ab=128,
                     channels=2,
                     samplerate=44100,
                     threads=4,
                     audio-sync=1}
       :standard{
                     access=http,
                     mux=ts,
                     mime=video/ts,
                     dst=0.0.0.0:8099}'
```

Comment: Terminal reads input options as one line so please use discretion.                                                                                                                                                                                  `cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0:chroma=h264:input-slave=alsa://hw:1,0:live-caching=200 --sout '#transcode{deinterlace,vcodec=h264,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100, threads=4,audio-sync=1}:standard{access=http,mux=ts,mime=video/ts,dst=0.0.0.0:8099}'`

Comment: I'm not seeing this work with my set up -- not sure why just yet.